# os.walk but with directories on top?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some simple code to print out the structure of a directory.
My example directory `ABC` contains subdirectory `A` containing `A.txt`, a subdirectory `Z` containing `Z.txt`, and a file `info.txt`. In real use, this will be big collection of many files and nested directories.

```
import os
topdir = 'ABC/'
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(topdir):
    print(os.path.join(dirpath))
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
```

The output is:

```
ABC/
ABC/info.txt
ABC/A
ABC/A/A.txt
ABC/Z
ABC/Z/Z.txt
```

How can I make it so directories are processed/printed on the top?
I want the output to replicate what I see in Windows Explorer, which displays directories first, and files after.

The output I want:

```
ABC/
ABC/A
ABC/A/A.txt
ABC/Z
ABC/Z/Z.txt
ABC/info.txt
```

Comment: Append result in list and sort it with length

Comment: or sort with count of path separators. `(/)`

Comment: Both the methods might not be accurate where `folder names are larger than filenames` or there are files in immediate directory (which will have only 1 `/` while sub-directories will have more than 1.

Comment: @Ben, you could just pull the `for` loop for printing filenames outside the loop for printing directory names (remove indentation) and that should do it.. it will first loop through the directories and then the files in the directory.

Comment: @ParvBanks This will only print the files in the very last directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without storing all the files in a list and sorting that list in one way or the other, you could make a recursive function and first recurse to the next level of the directory structure before printing the files on the current level:

```
def print_dirs(directories):
    try:
        dirpath, dirnames, files = next(directories)
        print(dirpath)              # print current path; no need for join here
        for _ in dirnames:          # once for each sub-directory...
            print_dirs(directories) # ... recursively call generator
        for name in files:          # now, print files in current directory
            print(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
    except StopIteration:
        pass

print_dirs(os.walk(topdir))
```

The same could also be done with a stack, but I think this way it's a little bit clearer. And yes, this will also store some directories in a list/on a stack, but not all the files but just as many as there are levels of nested directories.

Edit: This had a problem of printing *any* next directory on the generator, even if that's not a sub-directory but a sibling (or "uncle" or whatever). The `for _ in dirnames` loop should fix that, making the recursive call once for each of the subdirectories, if any. The directory itself does not have to be passed as a parameter as it will be gotten from the generator.

Comment: Your code works great with my initial example, thank you.
But testing with a different structure the output is not what I expected. Sorry to bother you.
I'm expecting dir A to output first, then A.txt, then dir Z, then Z.txt.

[output](https://i.imgur.com/3i7Jxxc.png)

Comment: @BenKailon Yes, I see the problem. The recursive call will not print the next sub-directory, but just the next in the original iterator, which might be a "sibling" directory. Give me a minute...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I'm not good with recursion and it's very helpful to see your comments to see how it works. Thanks!